# Choosing the alignment point(s) for aligned equations?

Tags: math-mode, align

So I have a couple of equations that I would like to align according to some letters with `\align*`:

**Current results:**

```
                    a) numbers + numbers = biggernumber
        b) morenumbers + morenumbers = muchbiggernumber
c) evenmorenumbers + evenmorenumbers = evenbiggernumber
                            d) etc. + etc. = etc.number
```

**Wanted result:**

```
a) numbers + numbers = biggernumber
b) morenumbers + morenumbers = muchbiggernumber
c) evenmorenumbers + evenmorenumbers = evenbiggernumber
d) etc. + etc. = etc.number
```

or:

```
a) numbers         +     numbers     =     biggernumber
b) morenumbers     +   morenumbers   = muchbiggernumber
c) evenmorenumbers + evenmorenumbers = evenbiggernumber
d) etc.            +       etc.      =       etc.number
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You probably want `alignat` rather than `align`.

Comment: Also check out flalign.  The last could be done with an array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `&` to set the alignment position. Below is first the original case with no alignment followed by your first wanted where the alignment is at `a)`, `b)` and so on. The second wanted alternative is better done using array. I have also included a version that in my opinion is easier to read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a)\ \text{numbers} + \text{numbers} = \text{bigger number}\\
  b)\ \text{more numbers} + \text{more numbers} = \text{much bigger number}\\
  c)\ \text{even more numbers} + \text{even more numbers} = \text{even bigger number}\\
  d)\ \text{etc.} + \text{etc.} = \text{etc. number}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  a)\ & \text{numbers} + \text{numbers} = \text{bigger number}\\
  b)\ & \text{more numbers} + \text{more numbers} = \text{much bigger number}\\
  c)\ & \text{even more numbers} + \text{even more numbers} = \text{even bigger number}\\
  d)\ & \text{etc.} + \text{etc.} = \text{etc. number}
\end{align*}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{ll@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}r}
    a) & \text{numbers} &{}+{}& \text{numbers} &{}={}& \text{bigger number}\\
    b) & \text{more numbers} &{}+{}& \text{more numbers} &{}={}& \text{much bigger number}\\
    c) & \text{even more numbers} &{}+{}& \text{even more numbers} &{}={}& \text{even bigger number}\\
    d) & \text{etc.} &{}+{}& \text{etc.} &{}={}& \text{etc. number}
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}

\begin{align*}
  a) && \text{numbers} + \text{numbers} &= \text{bigger number}\\
  b) && \text{more numbers} + \text{more numbers} &= \text{much bigger number}\\
  c) && \text{even more numbers} + \text{even more numbers} &= \text{even bigger number}\\
  d) && \text{etc.} + \text{etc.} &= \text{etc. number}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]